# Grails - Getting taglib bean via application context

Tags: grails, taglib, spring-bean

When attempting to get an instance to a custom taglib within a controller, via the following:

```
def myTagLib = grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean('com.mypackage.MyTagLib')
```

I recieve the following error:

> No bean named 'com.mypackage.MyTagLib' is defined. Stacktrace
>   follows:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   bean named 'com.mypackage.MyTagLib' is defined

However, I am able to get an instance of a built in taglib without issue:

```
def g = grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean('org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.ValidationTagLib')
```

According to the [following](http://coderberry.me/blog/2010/10/07/using-tag-lib-within-controllers-and-services/), this should work. Does anyone have any ideas why my taglib would not be recognized as a valid bean?

I am using Grails 2.4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Section 8.3.5](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#taglibs) of the Grails Documentation, if your taglib is namespaced (which is generally a good practice), you can simply call taglib methods by using your namespace as the prefix to the method call.

For instance, if you have a taglib namespaced "my" and it has a method called "smiley" that accepts an attribute "happy", you could have the following line in a controller with no extra imports necessary:

```
my.smiley(happy: true)
```

Comment: The above is true in a controller or another taglib, but is not true elsewhere. If you want to access the taglib from src/groovy files for example then you will need take your original approach. Because you are loading a bean, you want to use the registered name of the bean, not the class name.